# What is the proper way to have a user-authored EclipseLink DatabasePlatform subclass picked up?

Tags: eclipselink

The Informix support in EclipseLink 2.3.2 (and probably later) has a fairly serious bug in it where outer joins are not performed properly.  I'd like to subclass the EclipseLink `InformixPlatform` class to work around this.

For various reasons, I don't want to specify the database platform to use in my `persistence.xml`.  I would rather rely on EclipseLink's ability to discover the proper platform to use.

Obviously EclipseLink out of the box does not know about my subclass.  How can I tell EclipseLink that my subclass exists, and that it should be preferred to the normally-auto-discovered one?

For comparison purposes, Hibernate features a bit of machinery under the label of "dialect resolvers" that does exactly this: hand it a custom dialect resolver and it lets *you* deal with the autodiscovery process.  What is the equivalent in EclipseLink 2.3.2?

Comment: I see the `eclipselink.session-event-listener` property, but I am not sure if that is going after a mosquito with a steam hammer.  Would that be the proper approach?

Comment: Looking at the code, it would actually not work, because if I attempted to set the platform from my session event listener, it is immediately `null`ed out by `loginAndDetectDatasource()` after my listener returns!

Comment: Ugly: perhaps I should trap the `postLogin` event, logout, then set the platform I want to use, then login again.  I hope there's a better way!

Comment: This general approach does not appear to be working.  Doing this leads to `NullPointerException`s from within `QuerySequence` later, when you try to insert an entity with a table generator.  Running out of ideas.

Comment: I'm now going to try the `SessionCustomizer` approach.  There is no documentation on this class that indicates where in the lifecycle it is called.

Comment: The lifecycle is OK, but all the platform customization work that is performed here is overwritten.  I'm going to scream.

Comment: `SessionCustomizer` won't do it; see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401388.  There does not appear to be any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to programmatically install a `DatabasePlatform` subclass without running into other bugs.  See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=401388 for details.